# Webpage login button not working excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

The following code works on one computer but does not work on another.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.britishgas.co.uk/identity/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .document.getElementById("loginForm-email")
            .Focus
            .Value = "joe.bloggs@internet.com"
        End With
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        With .document.getElementById("loginForm-next")
            .Focus
            .Click
        End With

        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Without the "application.wait" instruction the button does nothing when clicked, but with the wait instruction is works.

However on this second computer even with the wait instruction the button does nothing.  I have tried varying the wait time but still does nothing.

Also on the computer where it does nothing, the "accept cookie" message keeps appearing each time the page loads.

Both computers are windows 10 IE11

Comment: Increase the delay and check again.

Comment: Have you pressed accept cookies? Then re-run?

Comment: yes, pressed the x, cookie message dissappears, but re-appears on the re-run.

Comment: Another difference, on the computer that works, the field blurs, but on the computer that does not work the field does not blur....